# VS2019 : Complex tree section for debugging simple string variables in VS2019

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

[image]

[image]

I'm debugging simple code in VS2019.
The value of string shown in debugger is looks like a complex tree.
How to make it easy view in debugger?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMShH.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "easy view"? There are options for customization, but you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: easy view is something simple value (e.g. "Dummy") instead of its Value {_Mypair=allocator}? Any Ideas?

Comment: Please see attached snapshot, 
where string value should be something like "Dummy". Instead I see its Value as 
{Mypair = allocator}

Comment: I resolved the issue.

Comment: Use this natvis file and place it in your vs2019 installation path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers)

Comment: I can't attach stl.natvis file. If anybody need this just ping me or email me: somumachani@gmail.com